# How Do I Disable AI Code Suggestions in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, ide, code-completion

I would like to disable the [AI code suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtdv1.png) in PyCharm. I noticed them when I updated to PyCharm 2023.3.2.

I looked up the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#troubleshooting) on Code Completion but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hover the mouse over the suggestion. You'll see a hover window like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6zmm.png). Press the "three dots" button and choose Settings - there you can disable the suggestions.
Actually, there are two types of AI Code Completions in PyCharm 2023.3: [local model](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#full-line-code-completion) based (enabled by default) and [cloud model](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/use-ai-in-editor.html#enable-inline-code-completion) based (enabled only if AI Assistant is enabled), following the links you can find more detailed information